# raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key)) KeyError: 'Worksheet Sheet does not exist.'

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-camelot

```
import os
import camelot
from openpyxl import Workbook

def extract_tables_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')
    return tables

def filter_rows_by_keywords(table, keywords):
    filtered_rows = []

    for row in table.df.itertuples(index=False):
        if any(keyword.lower() in str(cell).lower() for cell in row for keyword in keywords):
            filtered_rows.append(row)

    return filtered_rows

def export_filtered_rows_to_excel(tables, output_path, keywords):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for table in tables:
        filtered_rows = filter_rows_by_keywords(table, keywords)

        for row in filtered_rows:
            ws.append(row)

    wb.save(output_path)

def combine_sheets_to_single_sheet(workbook):
    combined_ws = workbook.create_sheet("Combined")
    source_sheets = workbook.sheetnames[:-1]

    for sheet_name in source_sheets:
        source_ws = workbook[sheet_name]
        
        for row in source_ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
            values = [cell.value for cell in row]
            combined_ws.append(values)

    workbook.remove(workbook["Sheet"])
    workbook.save(output_path)

# Specify the folder path containing the PDF files
pdf_folder_path = r"D:\Users\Home\Desktop\pastas\Premier\PDFs"
output_folder_path = r"D:\Users\Home\Desktop\pastas\Premier\PDFs"
output_excel_file = "filtered_rows.xlsx"
keywords = ["Cidade", "Data Pregão", 'Valor das Operações',"Quantidade Total", "Preço Médio", "Líquido para", "Corretagem"]

tables = []

# Extract tables from PDFs in the folder
for file in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, file)
        extracted_tables = extract_tables_from_pdf(pdf_path)
        tables.extend(extracted_tables)

# Filter desired rows and export to Excel
output_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, output_excel_file)
export_filtered_rows_to_excel(tables, output_path, keywords)

# Combine sheets into a single sheet
workbook = Workbook()
workbook = Workbook(output_path)
combine_sheets_to_single_sheet(workbook)

print(f"Filtered rows saved to {output_path}")
```

running the code manually by selecting everything and pressing CTRL ENTER ends up working partially but it keeps returning me, in between lines, the error in the title

```
>>> combine_sheets_to_single_sheet(workbook)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in combine_sheets_to_single_sheet
  File "D:\Users\Home\Desktop\pastas\Premier\Venvi\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))
KeyError: 'Worksheet Sheet does not exist.'
>>> print(f"Filtered rows saved to {output_path}")
Filtered rows saved to D:\Users\Home\Desktop\pastas\Premier\PDFs\filtered_rows.xlsx
```

i'm trying to extract rows from brokerage notes into excel that i will afterwards try to filter out, but first i'd like to understand why openpyxl is giving me this error

nothing really that i could get to work and nothing else i was able to find that seemed like what i wanted around here

Running the code through vscode's button gives me a syntax error for some reason

Comment: Probably the line `workbook.remove(workbook["Sheet"])` is the problem. There may be no sheet "Sheet".